# Using Omniauth on Rails, how do I change the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

Currently I have these two routes in my rake routes output:

```
user_omniauth_authorize
/users/auth/:provider(.:format)
devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter/}
user_omniauth_callback
/users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)
devise/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook|twitter)
```

What file do I have to change to customize these so the route can read:

```
user_omniauth_authorize
/admin/manage/:slug/auth/:provider(.:format)
devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|twitter/}
user_omniauth_callback
/admin/manage/:slug/auth/:action/callback(.:format)
devise/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook|twitter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => :omniauth_callbacks

devise_scope :user do
    match "/admin/manage/:slug/auth/:provider",
      :constraints => { :provider => /facebook|twitter/ },
      :to => "devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru",
      :as => :user_omniauth_authorize,
      :via => [:get, :post]

    match "/admin/manage/:slug/auth/:action/callback",
      :constraints => { :action => /facebook|twitter/ },
      :to => "devise/omniauth_callbacks",
      :as => :user_omniauth_callback,
      :via => [:get, :post]
end
```

Now, this is untested. I copied it from [Devise's source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L407-L417). So there are a couple of problems:

1. You have to add `user` to the `:as` alias, so it's not dynamic.
2. You have to add the auth providers to the constraints, so it's not dynamic.